# Delte rows in a range based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data on employees in the range Q6:V100. The data is not in table and the data consists of 6 columns(job title, duty, pay etc.) and based on the first column which is "Currently employed" I want to delete the row where the employee is not employed anymore (="").  The first column shows "O" if employed and ""(just a blank) if no  . This is the code I have tried. But it shows error message

> "Autofilter method of range class failed"

and I have no idea what is wrong... It will grateful if someone can help !

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value()

Dim ws As Worksheet


  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Trainings")
  ws.Activate

  'Clear any existing filters
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  '1. Apply Filter
  ws.Range("Q6:V100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""

  '2. Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Range("Q7:V100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  '3. Clear Filter
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question - if you remove the `On Error Resume Next`, does `ws.ShowAllData` throw an error?  (`ws.FilterMode` can be used to check if a Filter is active)

Comment: Your code works for me. If you step through are there actually any visible rows?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise a more robust system, with a notation in Column Q stating:
1 = Employed,
0 = Not employed

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Trainings")
    ws.Activate

Dim i As Integer
Dim n as Integer

    n = ws.Range("Q6").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    For i = n + 5 To 6 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(i, 17).Value = 0 Then
            ws.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

If you do not adapt the new system, change the If-statement to match your current system:

```
If ws.Cells(i, 17).Value = "" Then
```

Comment: Filtering is quicker than looping.

Comment: Indeed - but the range in question only contains 93 rows. So in my opinion, performance issues shouldn't be a concern.